# Multirow table with big column entries

Tags: multirow, adjustbox

I made this table but it doesn't fit the page. I tried `\adjustbox` but that seems to reduce the text size of the entries. I want the text size to be unchanged.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\def\arraystretch{3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|}
\hline
Superclass & Topic Words  \\ \hline
%0
\multirow{1}{*}{ruby} & \makecell[l]{block gems/redis lib/redis/client.rb         call gems/sidekiq lib/ruby/gems lib/redis.rb app/vendor/bundle/ruby tmp/build     c/vendor/bundle/ruby \\gems/railties vendor/bundle/ruby gems/activesupport         dda lib/ruby levels error actionpack lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb lt;top}\\
\hline

%1
\multirow{5}{*}{data-type} & \makecell[l]{key keys redis hash values set     data list store field string command hashes fields stored delete match array     pattern type}\\
\cline{2-2}
   &  \makecell[l]{list item items rpush lpush element lists default type     client lrange llen \\pop collection elements empty push true doctrine     mylist}\\
\cline{2-2}

& \makecell[l]{set sorted score sets list zadd member members elements         zset sadd element result timestamp sort scores order items time number}\\
\cline{2-2}

& \makecell[l]{string data json redis object bytes type int array length     byte strings store bit key convert size python result serialized}\\
\cline{2-2}

& \makecell[l]{val anonfun case def scala string play actor plugin future     sbt apply jar:na anon extends akka://application/user implicit\\ application-    akka.actor.default-dispatcher akka map}\\
\hline

%2
\multirow{2}{*}{commands} & \makecell[l]{info jan bytes total keys memory     time apr connected clients slaves hgets timer.caching volatile slots     usr/local/bin/php\\ usec\_per\_call usec used\_memory\_human stat}\\
\cline{2-2}
& \makecell[l]{key set keys time expire redis ttl counter exists count     command incr expiration expired expiry increment remove delete check     deleted}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output: [image: table]

Any potential solutions?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Solved for single page tables. It doesn't seem to work when table spans multiple pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you expect? You are using `makecell` and add a new line character `\\ ` only after some very long text. If you really fell that this is the way to go, i.e. to use `makecell` here, consider being more generous with `\\ `.

Comment: For a second column that has automated linebreaks and a table that is as wide as the textwidth, you can use the `tabularx` package.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

With use of table environment `tabularx` and its column type `X` the long text cells is automatically breaking into more lines. With the `ragged2e` packages is text in cells in the second table's column is "smart" flush left.

Changes in code in comparison with your table are marked by `% <---`

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % <---
\usepackage{makecell, multirow,
            tabularx}                   % <---
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells   % <--- for more vertica space in cells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L|}     % <---
    \hline
Superclass & Topic Words  \\ \hline
%0
\multirow[t]{5}{*}{ruby}
    &   block gems/redis lib/redis/client.rb
        call gems/sidekiq lib/ruby/gems lib/redis.rb app/vendor/bundle/ruby tmp/build     c/vendor/bundle/ruby gems/railties vendor/bundle/ruby gems/activesupport dda lib/ruby levels error actionpack lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb lt;top \\   % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \hline
%1
\multirow[t]{15}{*}{data-type}
    &   key keys redis hash values set data list store field string command hashes fields stored delete match array pattern type             \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \cline{2-2}
    &  list item items rpush lpush element lists default type client lrange llen pop collection elements empty push true doctrine mylist    \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \cline{2-2}
    &   set sorted score sets list zadd member members elements zset sadd element result timestamp sort scores order items time number         \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \cline{2-2}
    & string data json redis object bytes type int array length byte strings store bit key convert size python result serialized               \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \cline{2-2}
    &   val anonfun case def scala string play actor plugin future sbt apply jar:na anon extends akka: application/user implicit application- akka.actor.default-dispatcher akka map \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \hline%2
\multirow[t]{6}{*}{commands}
    &   info jan bytes total keys memory time apr connected clients slaves hgets timer.caching volatile slots usr/local/bin/php usec\_per\_call usec used\_memory\_human stat      \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
\cline{2-2}
    &   key set keys time expire redis ttl counter exists count command incr expiration expired expiry increment remove delete check deleted    \\ % <--- "makecell" is removed
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
    \end{table}
```

**Adendum:**

According for your comment below (that above solution doesn't work with multi page table), the following considerations are necessary:

- Table over multi page had not be inside float `table`.
- For such table have been developed special packages for tables as `longtable`, `ltablex`, xltabular (which combine`longtable` and `tabularx`).
- Use of the `multirow` cells can be fragile since it can be break over few pages with no indication of cell contents on its beginning.

An example of multi page table using `ltablex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % <---
\usepackage{ltablex,
            makecell, multirow,
            tabularx}                   % <---
\keepXColumns                           % <---
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}     % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells                         % <--- 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L|}     % <--- 
\caption{A test caption} 
\label{table2}                                  \\ 
    \hline 
Superclass                      & Topic Words   \\  
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{A test caption (cont.)}              \\
    \hline
Superclass                      & Topic Words   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
% table body
\multirow[t]{5}{*}{ruby}        & \lipsum[1]    \\  \hline
    \pagebreak
\multirow[t]{5}{*}{data-type}   & \lipsum[2]    \\  \cline{2-2}                 
                                & \lipsum[3]    \\  \cline{2-2} 
                                & \lipsum[4]    \\  \hline 
\multirow[t]{6}{*}{commands}    & \lipsum[5]    \\  \cline{2-2} 
                                & last row      \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabularx} 
    \endgroup 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works ona single page but messes up when table spans multiple pages.

Comment: sorry, you not mentioned in question, that you looking for multi page table. for it you need to use `longtable` or `ltablex` or some other package for such purpose.